# Change rem reference from html base font size to the div container font size

Tags: html, css, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm injecting UI using the shadow dom approach into web pages as a chrome extension. The [library](https://gourav.io/blog/tailwind-in-shadow-dom) I'm using to add styles inside the shadow dom uses rem instead of px and because of this, it's taking font-size reference from the HTML base font size. Some sites have different base font sizes so the shadow dom UI looks smaller or bigger on various sites.

Is there a way to tell shadow dom to use the base font size of 16px instead of taking reference from the HTML font size?

Comment: No, the CSS specification says `rem` is defined by the main document's root. As a workaround you can add your UI inside a src-less iframe or even in a [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) iframe.

Comment: best bet is to set the `:host` font size and then use `ems` instead of `rems`